# Despite loading new data from code, report displays original data

Tags: crystal-reports

as below i have code to display data,

it works very fine, while data available..

but it shows same data, if query doeent return any rows, it shows last loaded data,

even if query returns other data eventhough it shows last loaded data..

please help me out...

```
    ReportDocument rptdoc = new ReportDocument();

    Ds2 = new DataSet();
    Ds2 = ClsPos.GetRejectedByPosition(int.Parse(Request.QueryString.Get("ID")));

    string ReportName = Server.MapPath("RejectedCandidate.rpt");

    rptdoc.Load(ReportName);

    // Position Name
    ParameterFields Parameters = new ParameterFields();
    ParameterField idget = new ParameterField();
    idget.Name = "PositionName";
    ParameterDiscreteValue values = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    values.Value = Request.QueryString.Get("PositionName");
    idget.CurrentValues.Add(values);
    Parameters.Add(idget);

    CRViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = Parameters;

    rptdoc.SetDataSource(Ds2.Tables["GetValues"]);
    CRViewer1.ReportSource = ReportName;
    CRViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

use rptDoc.Refresh(); after loading report. i.e.

```
rptdoc.Load(ReportName);
rptDoc.Refresh();
```

Comment: Probably the refresh needs to happen at the end.